# Async functions within typeaheadjs

Tags: javascript, dom, promise, typeahead.js

This function works within `typeahead.js` context, 
 i use `lodash` `request-promise` and `cheerio` 
to grab/parse/organize my data.

`console.log` shows every variables as it should be.
but with this line :

`return '<p>' + img + data.name + ' - ' + getProviders(data) + '</p>'`

i get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

I'm not sure what's happening, this might have something to do with `typeahead.js` trying to happend an invalid (because incomplete yet) DOM element.

PS: `let img = $(selector).attr('src');` is intended (it stores the src attribute as a string)

PS2: if i ommit `img` it works: 
 `return '<p>' + data.name + ' - ' + getProviders(data) + </p>'`

```
function(data) {
  let imgProviders = _.keys(data.url).map((r) => {
    return {[r]: data.url[r]};
  });
  let url = imgProviders[0][_.keys(imgProviders[0])[0]].replace(/\/$/, '');
  let selector = _.find(sites, {
    providerName: _.keys(imgProviders[0])[0]
  }).coverIMG;

  let body = request.get(url, (err, res, html) => {
    $ = cheerio.load(html);
    // the variable that is messing with me 
    let img = $(selector).attr('src');
    // works fine when console.log()
    console.log(img, data.name, getProviders(data));
    return '<p>' + img + data.name + ' - ' + getProviders(data) + '</p>';
  });
}
```

Comment: are you saying that the code snippet works, but if you remove `<p>` and `</p>` from the return statement in `request.get` callback, you get the error?

Comment: What i mean is: `console.log` output the data fine.

but `return` doesn't work when i'm including something from the request.

Comment: oh, you want `body` in your code to be `'<p>' + img + data.name + ' - ' + getProviders(data) + '</p>'` - you do realise that the function you posted `function(data) {` doesn't return anything, because it has no return statement